# TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, deprecated

I am running this code to convert the sample_time variables to datetime. However, I am receiving this error: TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

How can I rectify this without changing my python version to an older non deprecated version?

```
df['sample_time'] = df['sample_time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%D %H:%M:%S'))
```

[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'sample_time' column is of `decimal.Decimal` type. Either convert that column to `float` or `int` before processing or do that in your `apply` statement:

```
df['sample_time'] = df['sample_time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(x / 1000)).strftime('%Y-%m-%D %H:%M:%S'))
```